# french chars html - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page were i can fill in some text and send  (with javascript) this to an sql-database.

On my pc, everything works fine, but on another one (a french windows), it doesn't save my chars correctly.

french chars like é, è, â,.. were saved as 'Ã‰', or something like that.

I googled a lot but still did not found any solution, i'm also not able to reproduce the problem on my own pc..

Answer (score 2):

"Ã‰" occurs when a character encoded in utf-8 (2 bytes) is read as latin (1 byte). The problem can be on the client side (e.g. by the use of `escape`) or on the server side (wrong parsing of the form's POST data, database encoding).

Comment: Beware: Until MS-SQL 2008, UTF-8 support was lacking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your html pages encoding is set to something like UTF-8, UTF-16, etc... Also make sure that your strings are escaped properly in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the file in ANSI. I do this my self. For example in notepad 2 you would click File->Encoding->ANSI and then save.